# MVC return json result with partial view and parameter from FilterConfig

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4

**View:**

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("CreateFolder", "Folder", FormMethod.Post, new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "CreateFolderSuccess" }))
{
Code blabla..
}
```

**Filter:**

Something like this..?

```
        filterContext.Result = new JsonResult
        {
                    ViewString = this.RenderViewToString("~/Views/Folder/ReadFolder.cshtml", null),
                    isRedirect = true
        };
```

**Script onsuccess:**

```
function CreateFolderSuccess(result) {
    if (result.isRedirect) {
        $('#LogInReload').html(result.ViewString);

    }
    else {
        $('#CreateReload').html(result);
    }
}
```

So I'm returning different partial views on different results.

**What i need help with:**

I dont really know how to return a partial view + parameter from FILTERCONFIG. I've done it before in my controller but not like this. I would love some help.. Thanks

**UPDATE 1:**

Forgot about my extension:

```
public static string RenderViewToString(this Controller controller, string viewName, object model)
{
    using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter())
    {
        ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(controller.ControllerContext, viewName);
        controller.ViewData.Model = model;
        ViewContext viewCxt = new ViewContext(controller.ControllerContext, viewResult.View, controller.ViewData, controller.TempData, writer);
        viewCxt.View.Render(viewCxt, writer);
        return writer.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: You're attempting to render a view from within an ActionFilter?

Comment: Yeah, that last edit is fairly important; your method is an extension of the `Controller` class, so it won't work from with an `ActionFilterAttribute` class.

Comment: Yea sorry about that:) Hmm ok.. Thanks